# What is the difference between buffered and unbuffered code?

Tags: javascript, pug

[This](http://jade-lang.com/reference/code/) documentation is confusing.

It says, unbuffered code does not output any code directly. What does that mean?

But in general, what is the difference between buffered and unbuffered code?

Would also be nice if they didn't disable copy and right click on the page too!

Comment: maybe someone else is able to help you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Please ignore this answer as it is incorrect as pointed out in the comments

I invite you to have a look at matty's answer instead.

---

From what I understand in the documentation link you shared I'd say there is a major difference:

---

**Unbuffered** code is not executed when read, but deferred (it is looks like javascript), which means that the string is post processed.

It seems that they map the string to an internal routine, that is hybrid js + templating language.

---

**Buffered** code is on the other hand executed as javascript (first it is preprocessed to escape html).
Though it seems to have a different behavior according to which code you put in there.

For example it is said that this:

```
p='Test' + ' concatenation'
```

Will result in `Test concatenation`

But now, you could do this:

```
p=(function() { return 'Does this really work ?! It seems so'; }())
```

It will result in `Does this really work ?! It seems so`.

It simply evals your code and escapes the html.

Comment: So buffered runs inline and buffered is saved up and run at the end? Sounds like the names are the wrong way around.

Comment: I guess you mean unbuffered is saved up, but I think their point for choosing buffered is more about the fact that it is not actually executed as real javascript (unbuffered) and buffered is. but you are still right, it seems that this terminology is confusing because it is more about the technique used to make it possible than about the actual use you can make of it.

Comment: yes i meant buffered is unbuffered. there's me moaning about documentation... :)

Comment: I don't believe the execution of unbuffered code is deferred. The difference between buffered and unbuffered is simply that the results of unbuffered code do not get sent to the output, while the results of buffered code, being the opposite, are sent to output. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31351523/1298086) for an example.

Comment: @matty Acknowledged - marking my answer as inappropriate in an edit to avoid harm to future viewers. I can't delete it until it is no longer accepted by OP.

Answer (score 16):

"Unbuffered" means that the code is executed, but the results **are not** sent to the output buffer.

"Buffered" **also** means that the code is executed, and the results **are** sent to the output buffer.

For example, this Jade:

```
.unbuffered
  - 'unbuffered vs buffered'

.buffered
  = 'unbuffered vs buffered'
```

Produces this HTML:

```
<div class="unbuffered">
</div>
<div class="buffered">unbuffered vs buffered
</div>
```

Comment: It would be more helpful to clarify that the buffered code appears in the rendered HTML whereas the unbuffered code doesn't.

Comment: I appreciate that clarification. However it's worth noting that producing output is the sole purpose of this particular buffer. It is in fact an *output* buffer. And specifically what's rendered is not a determination made by jade or pug.